Salesforce automation using Healenium(self healing java)
When I run with self healing on it is fetching and storing only few elements. Taking only main screen elements not able to heal new lead creation kind of boxes input... Not storing those elements in report also not showing but login id those things are shown.. Can someone please help
So salesforce automation using healenium is possible 100℅??

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
